# for loop problem after create firewall rule by using cloudflare api

Tags: for-loop, cloudflare

## Create new IP Firewall rules on Cloudflare

```
ASN_name=$(cat ASN_name.txt)
Notes=$(cat Notes.txt)

for ASN_name in $ASN_name;
do
 for Notes in $Notes;
 do  
  update=$(curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/xxxxxxxxxx/firewall/access_rules/rules" -H "X-Auth-Email: $auth_email" -H "X-Auth-Key: $auth_key" -H "Co
ntent-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"mode\":\"whitelist\",\"configuration\":{\"target\":\"asn\",\"value\":\"$ASN_name\"},\"notes\":\"$Notes\"}")

  if [[ $update != *"\"success\": true"* ]]; then
    message="$ASN_name **FAILED** to add. DUMPING RESULTS: $update"
    log "$message"
    echo -e "$message"
 #    #exit 1
  else
    message="$ASN_name successfully Added"
    log "$message"
    echo "$message"

 fi
 done
done
```

I need to set different ASN rule as different notes on the Cloudflare firewall rule via automation. Rule is successfully added but the notes in the firewall rules is not in my expected. as Below screenshot :
[script created firewall rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHiP3.png)
[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQm5v.png)

ASN_name.txt :

```
AS4134
AS4837
AS9808
AS9394
```

Notes.txt :

```
Chinanet-Backbone
CHINA-UNICOM-China169-Backbone
Guangdong-Mobile-Communication-CoLtd
China-TieTong-Telecommunications-Corporation
```